# How should a practical code example be structure to avoid callback hell?

Tags: node.js, callback, asynccallback

I've been suffering from callback hell in my JavaScript code and I believe this is caused by my previous experience in mainly purely synchronous/threaded Java code.

I learn well by example but have, as of yet, been unable to find a good "before and after" example of callback hell solved in many of the situations I find it occurring in.

I would appreciate it if some kind soul could show me what the code as provided below should be structure so as to avoid callback hell (using libraries such as async if necessary), as I believe a practical example would benefit me and others reading the question.

Wrangling with this for a while, I still could not figure out a way of it working well that would allow a call on the original callback as well as retaining the logic of the code.

Any help if well appreciated, thank you for your time. :)

Code:
    var fs = require('fs');
    var zlib = require('zlib');

```
var defaultOptions = require('./options/defaults');

function FeatherDB (sourcePath, options)
{
    if (options === undefined)
    {
        // use defaults if options not provided
        options = defaultOptions;
    }
    else
    {
        // ensure all keys are supplied
        for (key in defaultOptions)
        {
            if (options[key] === undefined)
            {
                options[key] = defaultOptions[key];
            }
        }
    }

    this.sourcePath = sourcePath;
    this.options = options;
}

FeatherDB.prototype.load = function (callback)
{
    var thiz = this;
    fs.exists(this.sourcePath, function (error, doesExist) {
        if (error)
        {
            callback(error);
            return;
        }

        if (doesExist)
        {
            fs.readFile(thiz.sourcePath, function (error, rawFileData) {
                if (error)
                {
                    callback(error);
                    return;
                }

                if (thiz.options.compress)
                {
                    zlib.gunzip(rawFileData, function (error, rawUncompressedData) {
                        if (error)
                        {
                            callback(error);
                            return;
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            thiz.documents = JSON.parse(rawUncompressedData.toString('utf8'));
                        }
                        catch (error)
                        {
                            callback(error);
                            return;
                        }

                        callback(null);
                    })
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        thiz.documents = JSON.parse(rawFileData.toString('utf8'));
                    }
                    catch (error)
                    {
                        callback(error);
                        return;
                    }

                    callback(null);
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            thiz.documents = {};
            callback(null);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: have you tried wait.for? https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I justed formatted it and removed the `fs.exists` check. If the file doesn't exist readFile will fail and send an error back.

```
FeatherDB.prototype.load = function (callback) {
    var thiz = this;

    fs.readFile(thiz.sourcePath, function (error, rawFileData) {
        if (error) {
            thiz.documents = {};
            return callback(error);
        }

        if (!thiz.options.compress) {
             FeatherDB.parse(rawFileData.toString('utf-8'), callback);
             return;
        }

        zlib.gunzip(rawFileData, function (error, rawUncompressedData) {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error);
            }
            FeatherDB.parse(rawUncompressedData.toString('utf-8'), callback);
        });
    });
}

FeatherDB.prototype.parse(data, callback) {
     try {
        thiz.documents = JSON.parse(data);
     } catch (error) {
        return callback(error);
     }

     callback();
}
```

If you start doing more nested stuff you can look into using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).* functions like waterfall, series, parallel etc.

Comment: Thank you, that's certainly an improvement :) Do you think there would be a way that ALL of the inline functions could be extracted and still retain sanity?

Comment: Well that depends on the function in this case the load function isn't that long after the parse is extracted out, but if the function was bigger then I would probably refactor it more and extract out more functions.